# How to get parameter value in views of coauchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have a document called login_data like-

```
{
   "name": "abc",
   "password": "abcd123",
   "user_id": "abc123"
}
```

and I am creating a view for checking the user_id and password is correct or not which is cumming from the URL.

And the code of view like-

```
function (doc, meta) { 
  if(doc.password && doc.user_id){
      emit("Status","Sucess");     
  }  
}
```

and my URL is like :-
http://localhost:8092/default/_design/dev_design/_view/login_credential?stale=false&inclusive_end=true&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0&password=%22abcd123%22&user_id=%22abc123%22

So how to get the param values in the views.Is there any other way to do this ,if any please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about what to emit and how to query a view.

The view is basically a simple index. First parameter of `emit` in the **map function** is the index key, and that is what you will use to query the view. Second parameter is an optional value associated with the key, upon which the **reduce function** can be run, to get statistics or an overall value for all documents matched by your view query...

Possible GET parameters of a view query are strictly defined, you cannot query arbitrary fields of the document if they are not part of this key you emitted.

For that **you should look at `N1QL` in Couchbase 4.0 and 4.1 instead.**